# Typescript typed function signature

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a typescript project and there's cases where I feel that I repeat myself and I don't know how to do it better. In case it matters, I'm using TypeScript 2.4

Consider this interface that accepts a `textFunction` property with a particular signature

```
export interface IDummyProps {
    textFunction?: (value: ExternalType) => string;
}
```

Then I have a getter in an ES6 class that provides a default implementation if a `textFunction` was not provided:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component<IDummyProps, any> {
    public get textFunction(): (value: ExternalType) => string; {
        return this.props.textFunction || String;
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to avoid typing `(value: ExternalType) => string` in two places?

Comment: Not very familiar with typescript, but typed languages often let you create *type aliases*. E.g. `type TextFunction = (value: ExternalType) => string;`. Typescript probably offers something similar.

Comment: @FelixKling That worked exactly haha. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently in English you would say "Every dog has its day" ;)